# Переадресация в .htaccess если отсутствует параметр в строке адреса

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, редирект

Ситуация следующая. Есть полная (старая) версия сайта, например "site.ru".

На субдомене поднята новая версия "new.site.ru".

Сейчас есть необходимость осуществлять автоматический редирект с главной страницы site.ru на страницу new.site.ru.

Но при этом, необходимо оставить доступной главную страницу site.ru, как вариант - не проводить редирект при наличии в строке адреса параметра full.

Возможно ли это вообще осуществить силами .htaccess?

Такой вариант работает на переадресацию с главной вне зависимости от параметров:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://new.site.ru/? [R=301,L]

Такой вариант работает на переадресацию с главной только С параметром:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^full$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://new.site.ru/? [R=301,L]

А как сделать наоборот? Переадресацию если без параметра

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^full$ [NC]` ?

Comment: Нет, такой вариант не работает.

Comment: Рабочий вариант:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.site.ru/? [R=301,L]